How does name resolution work with temporary stored procedures?
Say I have the following two databases
USE [master]
CREATE DATABASE Jack
GO

CREATE DATABASE Jill
GO

USE Jack
GO
CREATE TABLE JacksTable
(
    Id INT
)
INSERT INTO JacksTable VALUES (1)

If I create the following temporary stored procedure in the context of the Jack database:
USE Jack
GO

CREATE PROC #Temp
AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM    JacksTable
GO

and then execute in the Jack database:
USE Jack
GO
EXEC #Temp

I get the result 1
If I then run in the Jill database context:
USE Jill
GO
EXEC #Temp

I get 1
Now, if I drop the procedure
DROP PROC #Temp
and create the procedure again in the context of the Jill database:
USE Jill
GO

CREATE PROC #Temp
AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM    JacksTable 
GO

and run it
USE Jill
GO    
EXEC #Temp

I get an error
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure #Temp, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 74]
Invalid object name 'JacksTable'.

If I then try executing it from the Jack database:
USE Jack
GO
EXEC #Temp

I get
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure #Temp, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 74]
Invalid object name 'JacksTable'.

If I then drop the procedure
DROP PROC #Temp

Recreate in the Jill database context again
USE Jill
GO

CREATE PROC #Temp
AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM    JacksTable 
GO

and this time run from the Jack database
USE Jack
GO
EXEC #Temp

I get the same binding error
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure #Temp, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 74]
Invalid object name 'JacksTable'.

this tells me that SQL Server tries to bind the objects in the temporary procedure to the database which was in context when the temporary stored procedure was created.
this article suggests

When a stored procedure is executed for the first time, the query processor reads the text of the stored procedure from the sys.sql_modules catalog view and checks that the names of the objects used by the procedure are present.

Which database is this check performed against? I would assume it would be tempdb as that is the database in which the temporary stored procedures definition is persisted in? If so, that resolution would fail in all cases (unless we created the tables in tempdb) so it cannot be that.
Based on what I have seen above, it looks to be the database which was in scope when the temporary stored procedure was created (rather than the database the object definition is persisted in - tempdb) However, if that is indeed the case, how does SQL Server know which database that is and where is this stored? I have checked sys.sql_expression_dependencies, sys.sql_modules, sys.objects and sys.procedures and none seem to have that information

If you run a SELECT against sys.fn_dblog in tempdb after creating the proc you can see that the only places it writes to are

sys.sysschobjs
sys.syssingleobjrefs
sys.sysobjvalues
sys.syssoftobjrefs

You can only see these when connecting via the DAC but I just did so and it looks like indepid in tempdb.sys.syssingleobjrefs has this
SELECT p.id, 
       refs.indepid AS potential_database_id,
       p.name AS proc_name, 
       REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(imageval) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS proc_definition
FROM tempdb.sys.sysschobjs p
JOIN tempdb.sys.syssingleobjrefs refs ON p.id = refs.depid AND refs.class = 70 AND refs.depsubid = 0
JOIN tempdb.sys.sysobjvalues v on v.objid =p.id 
WHERE p.name LIKE '#Temp%' and p.type = 'P'

Searching sys.all_sql_modules for objects WHERE definition LIKE '%syssingleobjrefs%' AND definition like '%indepid%' doesn't show anything promising for getting this information without using the DAC.
sys.sql_modules does look at that column to determine the execute_as_principal_id but is filtering on  class = 22 in that case and I observed 70 for the entries returned by the above.

Thankyou. I never realised there were objects that can only be read under the DAC until now
